# IIS7 url rewrite for a specific port only

Tags: url, url-rewriting

i have a webserver that I want to redirect only port 8800 to a different server.  I want port 80 and 443 to be left on the same server.  I tried using ARP and reverse proxy in IIS7.  i created a reverse proxy rule that used the following parameters.

this is my inbound url
mydomain.com:8800

i want to route it to
myotherdomain.com

Wheni set this up it errors out and no one can access the website on any port.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

first bind mydomain.com:8800 to a website
then put config file to web root 
file name web.config
content is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="nexus respotory Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\.com$"/>

                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://myotherdomain/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```